# Annotate pdfs and insert pages

Tags: note-taking, pdf-viewer, presentation, academia

I teach mathematics in a university, often recording my lectures on a tablet (screencasting). Do you know if there is a PDF reader program that I can use during my lectures to:

1. display slides from a pdf file (in a slideshow-like fashion).
2. write annotations on them with a stylus.
3. insert pages on-the-fly in arbitrary places to add supplementary material, for instance proofs of theorems presented in the slides, again writing them with a stylus.

I could do all that with an older version of Xodo PDF, but apparently 3. is no longer supported.

Gratis or open source preferred. I'm restricted to use Windows 10 for external reasons.

Cross-posted from [academia.se](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125590/annotate-pdfs-and-insert-pages-for-proofs), where it didn't attract much interest.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the very late answer…

I use [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/) exactly for ①, ② and ③.

Xournal is available for Linux and Windows, I'm not aware of a Mac version. As far as I can tell, it's no more actively developed but it's available and reasonably maintained on major Linux distributions, while the Windows version probably is in a less sane state.

> From Xournal's site:
>
> [Win32 binaries](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/xournal/xournal-0.4.8.2016-win32.zip) of version 0.4.8.2016 are also available (note the windows version is less thoroughly tested and still unstable).

There is also [Xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp), a sort of fork of Xournal, that is actively developed and has a number of pleasant enhancements but, at least the last time I checked, fails at ① and so it's unsuitable for my use case and, in my understanding, also for yours but ymmv.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that in the past, but it had some issues with my Surface's stylus (spurious touch events registered). I will try it again anyway, maybe it has improved in the latest versions.